# SQL: Write a trigger that stops a row from being inserted if Person already owns a Store

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I have the following table called Manager:

```
Store   |   Person
ABC         Ms. Elara
XYZ         Mr. Saros
DEF         Ms. Orion
```

I am learning about triggers in PostgreSQL and I am trying to write a trigger for the above table to check and disallow any insert or update of a Person in the Manager table to be a manager of more than one store.

My approach is that in the trigger function, you select tuples from the Manager table where the Person is equal to the Person in the tuple you are trying to insert. If there are tuples in the Manager table where the Person is equal to the Person in the new tuple to be inserted, then the row will not be inserted.

I am not sure how in the trigger function I can select all the tuples from Manager where the Person is equal to the Person to be inserted. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a unique index:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Manager_IDX ON Manager (person);
```

This would also work if you tried to update a person's name to a name that already exists. It would also have the benefit of making it quick to query the table by a person's name.

You did say you wanted to learn about triggers, one way to start might be to have a trigger (actually 3, an insert, update and delete trigger) on manager that automatically keeps a historical record of changes (i.e. an audit trail) in another table (e.g. manager_audit). The audit table will have the same definition as the Manager table, but with at least one extra column (e.g. opcode) that tracks what the operation was. e.g. I for insert, D for Delete, U for Update. You could also have a timestamp to record when the operation happened and other fields (e.g. the user id who did the change etc).

Having said all of that and for whatever it is worth, enforcing uniqueness on things like name might not be the best idea. It is entirely possible that "Mr. Smith" might be the name of two different people that happen to be working in a large company.

Another factor you might want to consider is performance. If you use a select based method to ensure uniqueness on a non index column/columns, you will require an "all row scan" of the table to execute that test. This will be true no matter how you implement it (e.g. trigger, function, procedure or whatever).

Put another way, lets say you have 100 managers and you want to insert a new one. A select based check will require that you scan the entire table (i.e. 100 rows) to see if the name already exists. As the table grows the scan will also grow. Over time you will encounter the phenomena of "degraded performance". As the table reaches millions or billions of rows, your "single record insert" will actually require billions of I/O's.

Indexes don't work that way. Indexes are essentially inverted sub-tables where the columns you nominate (e.g. manager.person) are the "key". As such the will only require a single I/O to perform the necessary checks - irrespective of how many records there may be in it.

*disclaimer* for the purists, I'm defining an I/O as a logical "record level" I/O, not a physical disk I/O or any other type of I/O. Thus one record read = 1 I/O, one record write = 1 I/O.

Comment: @ceno980 . . . Perhaps the most important thing to learn about triggers is when to use them and when not to use them.  Your example (as explained here) is not suitable for a trigger; there are much better cases where triggers are the best -- or at least a very reasonable -- solution.

Comment: @ceno980 if this has helped you, could you please accept the answer (click on the grey check mark next to the answer) and upvote it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a trigger for this ? U can write a postgres function that checks for the existence of a particular person before insert.

Something like this,

```
Create function check_person_exists(par_person_id int)
Declare var_exists_flag int;
Begin
var_exists_flag =0;p

Select 1 from table where person_id = par_person_id into var_exists_flag;
If var_exists_flag = 0
Then
Insert into ....
Else 
Raise notice ' the records already exists';
Return;
End
```

PS: The above code will have syntax issues .